# CSS3 @font-face not displaying on Mac OS X Safari 5.x OR Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, css, safari, font-face

Hi guys having a bit of a dilemna with @Font-Face and can't figure out why. I have done countless hours of research on the best @font-face code to use and troubleshooting as to why it would not display on a Mac OS X browser.

The current situation is, I am using...

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Avenir LT 55 Roman';
src: url('fonts/avenir-55.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('fonts/avenir-55.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('fonts/avenir-55.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/avenir-55.svg#AvenirLT-Roman') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

And the resulting page displays as so...

*Windows OS - Works on all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE)

*Apple Mac OS X - Works on Firefox and Safari 6.x but NOT on Chrome or Safari 5.x

*Apple iOS iPhone and iPad - Works fine

I'd appreciate any guidance on this matter.

If you want to see it for yourself have a look at http://gradtouch.com/test

I'm just so confused as to why it won't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine on my Mac could it be a cache issue?

Comment: Definitely not a cache issue. I ran it on a Macbook 2008 (Safari 6.0) it works, ran it on a Macbook 2007 (Safari 5.0.3) it doesn't display. Also tried Adobe BrowserLab (https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#) and it doesn't display. 
What version are you running Allan out of interest? Any ideas?

Comment: Working fine here (OSX 10.8.2 / Chrome latest) (using the woff). But the thing is that I've downloaded your ttf file and it seems to be corrupted (its preview is cropped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `ttf` file (it's corrupted - it seems like the baseline is altered in a way that the font appears heavily cropped) and that is why you get this behavior. Browsers that serve the other formats (eot, woff, svg) work nice but when a browser choses to serve the `ttf` you get a blank page (although technically there isnt any error). Fix your file and you'll be good to go.

This is your `woff` file:
[image]

And this is your `ttf` file:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Alladinian! I've fixed the ttf file now but it still refuses to appear in the browser. I've emptied the cache and everything. However it now appears in Adobe BrowserLab at least. Can you confirm its working now?