# CSS3 @font-face not selectable on Mac OS X Firefox

Tags: macos, css, firefox, text, font-face

Off the back of this post ([CSS3 @font-face not displaying on Mac OS X Safari 5.x OR Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269872/css3-font-face-not-displaying-on-mac-os-x-safari-5-x-or-chrome)) I have come across a new stumbling block. It all seemed to be fixed at first but then I encountered a new problem that I couldn't select any text.

On Firefox in Mac OS X, I cannot highlight any text or even click on any hyperlinks that is using the font-face font.
It is selectable on all other operating systems (including Windows, iOS etc.) and other Mac OS X browsers (like Chrome and Safari).

Try it out on http://gradtouch.com/test

Here's the current CSS code.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Avenir LT 55 Roman';
src: url('fonts/avenir-55.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
url('fonts/avenir-55.woff') format('woff'), 
url('fonts/avenir-55.ttf')  format('truetype'),
url('fonts/avenir-55.svg#AvenirLT-Roman') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Any ideas or solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, I would guess something is wrong with the metrics in that font.  If I create a `<span>` containing some of your text and give it a border to see how tall it is, that `<span>` ends up 0px tall.

Once that happens, selection will be invisible, since it's drawn to the height of the text...

Comment: Thanks Boris. How would I go about investigating it a bit more? Which file could be corrupt? (i.e. Which file does Firefox on Mac OS X use to render the font? - As it only appears to happen on that specific environment!) Really appreciate your help!

Comment: At first glance, looks like the .woff is the only one Firefox downloads.

Comment: I've adjusted the code and tried it on sauce labs and seems to work by moving TTF above WOFF. Can you confirm it works on your Firefox on Mac now and that you can highlight the text? Thanks again really appreciate your help!

Comment: @GradTouch Yep, it works for me now.  I wonder what's up with the woff file there.....

Comment: Thanks again Boris for your help. Yeh I can't figure out whats wrong with the WOFF file. I've tried reconverting from the original font (TTF) and it still has the same behaviour. Very strange!